# action on parent's sibling in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="btn-group js_publish_management>
    <button class="btn btn-danger js_publish_btn">Not Published</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success js_publish_btn">Published</button>
    <button type="button" t-attf-class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="js_publish_btn">
                <span class="css_unpublish">Unpublish</span>
                <span class="css_publish">Publish</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now i want to select parent's sibling button using jQuery.

If i click on any `<span>` of **li** element then how can i perform some action on `<button>` 
I am not so aware of jQuery selector. Thanks in advance for help.

relevant Demo [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/deC37/310/)

In above demo, If user clicks on NO button, it will become 'loading...'
I want this like: User clicks on NO-2 from dropdown then also NO button should become 'loading'

Comment: The use-case is very simple, but your bad use of class names made it tough. You should always keep a convention to separate and traverse the DOM easily.

Comment: is it possible for you to change the DOM?

Comment: @Vijay why not. to be frank i am very new! can you guide? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you may change your HTML too, there are much better ways to sync up the pairs of buttons. Decorating them with `data-` attributes is probably the easiest way to make the code data driven.

Your JSFiddle has some *odd* code. *document ready* events only apply to the initial page load, whereas you seem to be using it to simulate a load using a loop (which will not work as it will complete on the same browser frame). Also document load does not return a promise so `.then` will just cause an error.

I replaced the load simulation with a loadData function that does return a `promise` and completes after 3 seconds.

I have reworked your code so that the various buttons have a `data-target` referring to their matching button (in the drop down, or the main buttons).

e.g.

```
<button id="Unpublish" data-target="#UnpublishLink" class="btn btn-danger js_publish_btn">No</button>
```

When a button is clicked, it creates a jQuery object referring to both the button clicked and the matching pair:

```
// Add any matching button
$el = $el.add($el.data('target'));
```

It then does any button login ("loading..." etc) on both buttons.

```
$el.button('loading');
loadData().then(function (result) {
    $el.toggleClass("css_unpublished css_published");
    $el.button('reset');
}).fail(function (err, data) {
    $el.button('reset');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/deC37/312/

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this could work:

```
$("li span").click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass("css_unpublish")) {
       var buttons = $(this).closest(".btn-group").find("button.classForPublish");
   } else {
       var buttons = $(this).closest(".btn-group").find("button.classForUnpublish");
   }
})
```

Comment: Why `.parents(".btn-group")` and not `.closest(".btn-group")` Parents can return more than one...

Comment: This would return all the buttons....he wants similar buttons like "NO" for "NO-2" and "Yes" for "Yes2"

Comment: I edited my answer you just need to add those classForUnpublish and classForPublish to your html

Comment: The buttons and links are in matched pairs. Clicking either should update the status of two elements (one link and one button). This will not do that. The original question also has a number of extra issues not related directly to the title